# $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^k \cdot C(n,k)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Use the Binomial Theorem to Show

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^k \cdot C(n,k)$$

I'm not sure where to start here . . . I know it is missing an $a^{n-k}$ and a $b^{k}$ term that maybe I should set to be 1?

Comment: Show what? This isn't a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: You have the $b^k$ factor: it’s $(-1)^k$. The $a^{n-k}$ is invisible, because $a=\dots$?

Comment: Thanks! i get it now. So . . the answer is just as simple as $\sum_{i=0}^n C(n,k) \cdot (-1)^k \cdot 1^{n-k}$ ?

Comment: @rbtLong: That’s right, together with the fact that that sum is the binomial expansion of $\big(1+(-1)\big)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. What is $0=(1+(-1))^n$ according to the binomial theorem?

Comment: +1. The rate at which some answers are given, I won't be surprised if an answer is posted to a question even before the question is asked.

Comment: @user17762 I cannot claim I'm the fastest gun in SE, though!

Comment: LOL yes you are faster than light itself.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff There are a lot of competitors (including you and me) for the fastest gun in SE!

Comment: @user17762 I feel Brian will get accepted though... ¬¬